# Two salts vessels are connected to each other

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Two salts vessels are connected to each other. In the first vessel is 1.5 liters per minute in and 100 grams per liter of salt. In the second vessel is 1 liters per min, and at 300 grams per liter salt. The vessels are connected and there is 3 liters per minute from vessel 1 to vessel 2. Conversely, there is going from vessel 2 to vessel 2 at 1.5 liters per minute. There will also be 2.5 liters per minute away from the second vessel.

I already tried the equation with I had as followed:

\begin{aligned}
\dot x_1 (t) &= -\frac{3}{V_1} x_1 + \frac{1.5}{V_2} x_2 + 0.150\\
\dot x_2 (t) &= -\frac{4}{V_2} x_2 + \frac{3}{V_1} x_1 + 0.300t
\end{aligned}

with $V_1$ and $V_2$ the volume of vessel one and two and with $x_1$ and $x_2$ the concentration of salt.  Then I tried to find the start conditions but I'm not sure about them. I need to find the equilibrium point and then solve the equation. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Please explain what "In the first vessel is 1.5 liters per minute in and 100 grams per liter of salt" means.

Comment: there will be 1,5 l/min and 100g/l added to the first vessel. By the second vessel there will be added 1l/min and 300g/l.